# getting org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved error

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have made the maven clean install on one machine (machine 1) build was successful, I have copied the maven m2 repo on another machine (machine 2) and tried to run maven clean with offline option

```
mvn clean install -o
```

getting the below error.

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one
>   of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access
>   autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin
>   (http://autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repo)
>   in offline mode and the artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.2 has not been
>   downloaded from it before.

My requirement is to we need to ship maven repo to client and he will be running with

```
mvn clean install -o.
```

Comment: Why is there an URL downloading Maven artifacts from a SVN repoistory?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may change the maven settings of eclipse in machine 2.

Eclipse -> Window -> preference -> search maven -> User settings,modify the user maven settings file location(you may copy from machine 1), and see the Local Repository.

[maven user settings in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPGIl.png)

Comment: Hi Xie Iam not using eclipse , its just i have moved the whole /home/.m2 repo from machine 1 to machine 2(target machine) where i want to run mvn clean install -o, i have the source code in machine2 , i just want to build with the shipped repo in machine2.

Comment: if you mean using mvn command in the source code folder, please make sure you have installed the maven. Using `mvn -v` to see.

Comment: Yes maven is installed in machine 2

Comment: Thanks Tim, issue got fixed, there was diffrence in maven version, with identical versions in machine2 worked

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically telling you two things:

1. It cannot find the dependency: autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin
2. It is trying to download this dependency from the global maven repository, but as you are running it in offline mode, it is not allowed to do so.

Check on the second machine to see if the dependency exists, and if the dependency files are there. If it is only complaining about this dependency and the rest are okay, then you are most probably be referencing the repository correctly, and the error is due to missing files.

It is difficult to debug this issue just by the error message as this might be a knock-on from another configuration error.

Comment: Hmm, yes, as you mentioned it is complaining only about this dependency, Rest looks good, I have checked org/apache/maven/plugins folder in. M2 repo, the jar exists